# SQL Server 2008 Performance Difference for same query on 2 servers with same data

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a simple query such as

```
Select COLA 
from tableA 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from tableB
                  where COLA = tableB.colb)
and tablea.colc = 2
```

I have 2 identical servers with the same data set (restored from a backup). On one of them the query returns in 4 seconds on the other one (Production Server) I have let it run 5 minutes before killing it. The estimated plan is identical on both servers.  Where else and what else can I look at to find the difference in performance.  I know there is a better way to write the query but it is a query in a purchased product that we should not change.

Comment: Statistics get updated every night so they are current

Answer (score 0):

Statistics could be out of date or there could be blocking on the prod server due to more usesrs or more automated jobs running.

Comment: Statistics are updated nightly and we have run test during scheduled down time with no other users and get the same results

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `SQL Profiler`?

While using the `SQL Profiler`, don't forget to select the `Database Name` in `Trace` Properties as shown below.

Database name
[image: Click here to see Database Name setting]

Database Table
[image: Click here to see Database table setting]

Comment: I tried using profiler but since the query never finishes on prod (10 minutes, no locking involved) I cannot compare the differences in the results

Comment: @KeithMiller Did you increase the RAM for the Virtual machine ?

Comment: It is the VM that is Fast and Prod (physical) that is slow

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious but what are the hardware differences? Also, does the size of the table and the dataset that it has to parse, are they the same?

What kind of indexing are you using on these instances. Does the Production instance run on a VM?

Comment: The size of the table and dataset are identical. Just learned that the  production environment is a physical box and the other is a virtual. Would that do it?

Comment: Thats quirky. Usually a VM has share resources and you can actually control the amount of resources you allocate to a particular instance. Anything on the amount of RAM that your production has? I mean, any differences between the production and the other environment in terms of hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that one box is physical while the other is virtual, I'm betting that's the problem right there.  Virtual systems have to share resources with the other (physical) side of the box.  Also, there might be performance tweaks for the physical box since it's not running in a virtual environment.

CASE: Denali has "processor Affinity Masking" that can limit the amount of processor usage for each instance.

Either way, I'm willing to bet that it's due to the virtual environment versus the physical.

Hope this helps!